# Golang framework Организация кода

Tags: golang

Как вы пишете валидацию и запросы в базу (без orm)?
К примеру так:

```
//создаем структ регистрации формы
type UserRegister struct {
    Email    string    `validate:"required,max=20,min=8"`
    Password string `validate:"required,max=20,min=8"`
    Captcha  string `validate:"required,captcha"`
} 

//Создаем метод вставки в базу юзера
func (u *UserRegister) Insert() {
    //код вставки
}

//Проверяем вставляем
func Controller(n *N) {
    var userRegister UserRegister
    err := validator.Validate(&userRegister)
    if err == nil {
        userRegister.Insert()
    }
}
```

Или вот так:

```
//Основной структ юзера
type User struct {
   Id       int
   Email    string
   Password string
   Active   int
   //еще какието столбцы таблицы юзера
}

//методы для работы с юзером user.Insert(), user.SelectById() и т.д.
...

//
type UserRegister struct {
    Email    string    `validate:"required,max=20,min=8"`
    Password string `validate:"required,max=20,min=8"`
    Captcha  string `validate:"required,captcha"`
}

//Проверяем - копируем в основной struct юзер - вставляем
var userLogin UserRegister
err := validator.Validate(&userRegister)
if err == nil {
    //Копируем в основной юзер структ
    user := User{
        Email:    userRegister.Email,
        Password: userRegister.Password,
        ...
    }
    //Вставляем
    user.Insert()
}
```

То есть создаем структ и методы для работы с этим структом ИЛИ ЖЕ создаем основной структ с методами, а другие структы только для валидации и после валидации копируем данные в основной структ для работы с базой!?
Как правильно(лучше, удобней, почему)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я делаю так:

```
type DB interface {
    Query(string, ...interface{}) (*sql.Rows, error)
    // ...
}

func CreateUser(db DB, user *User) error {
    // ...
}
```

Это позволяет не делать лишних сущностей (типа UserRepository), а так же сочленять между собой вызовы с транзакциями:

```
tx, err := db.Begin()
// check err
err = CreateUser(tx, user)
// check err
err = CreatePost(tx, post)
// check err
err = tx.Commit()
// check err
```

А валидации я бы скрыл:

```
func ValidateUser(user *User) error {
    // ...
}
```

Эту функцию сделал бы экспортируемой, а внутри делал всё, что хочу. То есть хоть присваивать отдельной структуре и валидировать, хоть каждое поле вручную. Детали скрыты от пользователя модуля.

Comment: Вообщем в целом я с вами согласен, примерно также делают многие, вот [ТУТ](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/1vlj9e/complete_opensource_go_web_apps/) нашел ссылки на уже готовые проекты, полистал их, все стало понятней...